# Prism third party control assembly in module

Tags: wpf, module, prism, .net-assembly

I have a prism app where I've added a third party WPF control library to one of my modules.

I get an exception that the dll cannot be found when I run my application. Using fusion log viewer I see that the assembly is being looked for in the shell prject bin rather than in the module.

If I were to add a reference to the shell as well then that would get it working but clearly would break the point of a modular design.

Anyone else have experience of how to get this working?

Comment: Does your third-party control library get copied together with your module assembly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To handle this kind of deployment problem, I usually execute an [xcopy](http://www.computerhope.com/xcopyhlp.htm) command on Visual Studio project post-build events, to copy all modules dependencies and even modules themselves ( when there are no direct references between projects, and that should not be the case normally) into the running folder (the shell bin folder).

Riana

Comment: +1. If you don't want to reference the DLL from the shell, then a post-build event is the best option.

Comment: Ok, will do. Thanks for both comments.